# Warnings in R - making note

Tags: r, warnings

I'm trying to run a function (glm) in R 1000 times (with slightly different inputs each time). Sometimes I'll get a warning (because separation occurs) - all I want to do is count how many times this occurs (so how many times in the 1000 iterations I get the warning "glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred").

So my code would look something roughly like:

```
warningCount <- 0
for(i in 1:1000) {
  [generate data]
  glm(y ~ ., family="binomial", data=generated_data)
  if( I got the warning ) warningCount <- warningCount + 1
}
```

I just want to know how to write the line if( I got a warning ) properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `tryCatch()` to catch, inspect, and act upon the warnings.

```
## A function that randomly emits one of two warnings
f <- function() if(runif(1) > .7) warning("Ouch") else warning("Hmmm")

## A function to catch and process warnings, adding to a global counter
## when one of them includes the string "Ouch"
saidOuch <- function(w) {
    if(grepl("Ouch", as.character(w))) {ww <<- ww+1}
}

## Run your analyses, each wrapped in a tryCatch()
ww <- 0
for(i in 1:100) tryCatch(f(), warning = saidOuch)
ww
## [1] 32
```

---

For your specific case, if you decide not to deal with the issue of perfect separation in [some other way](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression), you can catch and count warnings with a function like this:

```
perfectSeparation <- function(w) {
    if(grepl("fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred",
             as.character(w))) {ww <<- ww+1}
}

## Test it with a function that will fit glm's that often emit the warning of interest
fitglm <- function() {
    dat <- data.frame(x=rnorm(3), y=sample(0:1, 3, replace=TRUE))
    glm(y~x, data=dat, family="binomial")
}
ww <- 0
for(i in 1:100) tryCatch(fitglm(), warning = perfectSeparation)
ww
# [1] 45
```

Comment: If running the glm (or in your example, f) gives two warnings e.g.:
"Warning messages:
1: [a different warning]
2: [the one I'm looking for]"
then ww doesn't increase by one - I've tried to ammend it so it does work, but haven't had any success. Just wondering if you know how to ammend that so it would still do ww <<- ww+1.

Comment: Maybe, to debug, put a call to `browser()` in the body of `saidOuch()`, so that you can inspect the warning object `w` directly, and play around with your `grepl()` call until it correctly matches? Without seeing your actual code, I won't be able to help much more...

Comment: @hodgenovice -- After taking a closer look at the specific warning mentioned in your question, I've revised my answer to more directly address it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tryCatch` to get the warning properly:

```
lapply(1:1000, function(u){
    [generate some data]
    tryCatch(glm(y ~ ., family="binomial", data=generated_data),
             warning = function(w) list(glm(y ~ ., family="binomial", data=generated_data), w)
})
```

Here it catches both warning and results, but you can only catch the warning if you want.